# Nivo Responsive Bar (TypeError: instruction.match is not a function)

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am new to react and I am trying to implement a responsive bar using the library "NIVO". I am currently following the codes shown in the following [link](https://nivo.rocks/bar). I have directly copied and pasted the codes from there to see if it works the codes I used can be found below

graphBar.js (My implementation of Responsive Bar)

```
import ResponsiveBar from '../node_modules/nivo/lib/components/charts/bar/ResponsiveBar'
import ResponsiveHeatMap from '../node_modules/nivo/lib/components/charts/heatmap/ResponsiveHeatMap'
import React from 'react';
// make sure parent container have a defined height when using
// responsive component, otherwise height will be 0 and
// no chart will be rendered.
// website examples showcase many properties,
// you'll often use just a few of them.
const MyResponsiveBar = (props) => {
    const data = [
        {
            "country": "AD",
            "hot dog": 87,
            "hot dogColor": "hsl(260, 70%, 50%)",
            "burger": 142,
            "burgerColor": "hsl(84, 70%, 50%)",
            "sandwich": 191,
            "sandwichColor": "hsl(20, 70%, 50%)",
            "kebab": 193,
            "kebabColor": "hsl(357, 70%, 50%)",
            "fries": 9,
            "friesColor": "hsl(283, 70%, 50%)",
            "donut": 78,
            "donutColor": "hsl(75, 70%, 50%)"
          },
          {
            "country": "AE",
            "hot dog": 111,
            "hot dogColor": "hsl(359, 70%, 50%)",
            "burger": 78,
            "burgerColor": "hsl(182, 70%, 50%)",
            "sandwich": 193,
            "sandwichColor": "hsl(65, 70%, 50%)",
            "kebab": 32,
            "kebabColor": "hsl(123, 70%, 50%)",
            "fries": 57,
            "friesColor": "hsl(232, 70%, 50%)",
            "donut": 176,
            "donutColor": "hsl(118, 70%, 50%)"
          },
          {
            "country": "AF",
            "hot dog": 105,
            "hot dogColor": "hsl(348, 70%, 50%)",
            "burger": 87,
            "burgerColor": "hsl(103, 70%, 50%)",
            "sandwich": 140,
            "sandwichColor": "hsl(327, 70%, 50%)",
            "kebab": 49,
            "kebabColor": "hsl(347, 70%, 50%)",
            "fries": 154,
            "friesColor": "hsl(332, 70%, 50%)",
            "donut": 168,
            "donutColor": "hsl(158, 70%, 50%)"
          },
          {
            "country": "AG",
            "hot dog": 115,
            "hot dogColor": "hsl(11, 70%, 50%)",
            "burger": 68,
            "burgerColor": "hsl(33, 70%, 50%)",
            "sandwich": 73,
            "sandwichColor": "hsl(209, 70%, 50%)",
            "kebab": 78,
            "kebabColor": "hsl(247, 70%, 50%)",
            "fries": 157,
            "friesColor": "hsl(141, 70%, 50%)",
            "donut": 86,
            "donutColor": "hsl(195, 70%, 50%)"
          },
          {
            "country": "AI",
            "hot dog": 91,
            "hot dogColor": "hsl(88, 70%, 50%)",
            "burger": 69,
            "burgerColor": "hsl(233, 70%, 50%)",
            "sandwich": 158,
            "sandwichColor": "hsl(106, 70%, 50%)",
            "kebab": 31,
            "kebabColor": "hsl(184, 70%, 50%)",
            "fries": 189,
            "friesColor": "hsl(98, 70%, 50%)",
            "donut": 199,
            "donutColor": "hsl(195, 70%, 50%)"
          },
          {
            "country": "AL",
            "hot dog": 91,
            "hot dogColor": "hsl(298, 70%, 50%)",
            "burger": 165,
            "burgerColor": "hsl(68, 70%, 50%)",
            "sandwich": 23,
            "sandwichColor": "hsl(299, 70%, 50%)",
            "kebab": 135,
            "kebabColor": "hsl(159, 70%, 50%)",
            "fries": 187,
            "friesColor": "hsl(200, 70%, 50%)",
            "donut": 138,
            "donutColor": "hsl(38, 70%, 50%)"
          },
          {
            "country": "AM",
            "hot dog": 0,
            "hot dogColor": "hsl(126, 70%, 50%)",
            "burger": 105,
            "burgerColor": "hsl(295, 70%, 50%)",
            "sandwich": 24,
            "sandwichColor": "hsl(120, 70%, 50%)",
            "kebab": 158,
            "kebabColor": "hsl(212, 70%, 50%)",
            "fries": 42,
            "friesColor": "hsl(171, 70%, 50%)",
            "donut": 7,
            "donutColor": "hsl(99, 70%, 50%)"
          }
    ]
    return (
        <ResponsiveBar
            data={data}
            keys={[ 'hot dog', 'burger', 'sandwich', 'kebab', 'fries', 'donut' ]}
            indexBy="country"
            margin={{ top: 50, right: 130, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
            padding={0.3}
            colors={{ scheme: 'nivo' }}
            defs={[
                {
                    id: 'dots',
                    type: 'patternDots',
                    background: 'inherit',
                    color: '#38bcb2',
                    size: 4,
                    padding: 1,
                    stagger: true
                },
                {
                    id: 'lines',
                    type: 'patternLines',
                    background: 'inherit',
                    color: '#eed312',
                    rotation: -45,
                    lineWidth: 6,
                    spacing: 10
                }
            ]}
            fill={[
                {
                    match: {
                        id: 'fries'
                    },
                    id: 'dots'
                },
                {
                    match: {
                        id: 'sandwich'
                    },
                    id: 'lines'
                }
            ]}
            borderColor={{ from: 'color', modifiers: [ [ 'darker', 1.6 ] ] }}
            axisTop={null}
            axisRight={null}
            axisBottom={{
                tickSize: 5,
                tickPadding: 5,
                tickRotation: 0,
                legend: 'country',
                legendPosition: 'middle',
                legendOffset: 32
            }}
            axisLeft={{
                tickSize: 5,
                tickPadding: 5,
                tickRotation: 0,
                legend: 'food',
                legendPosition: 'middle',
                legendOffset: -40
            }}
            labelSkipWidth={12}
            labelSkipHeight={12}
            labelTextColor={{ from: 'color', modifiers: [ [ 'darker', 1.6 ] ] }}
            legends={[
                {
                    dataFrom: 'keys',
                    anchor: 'bottom-right',
                    direction: 'column',
                    justify: false,
                    translateX: 120,
                    translateY: 0,
                    itemsSpacing: 2,
                    itemWidth: 100,
                    itemHeight: 20,
                    itemDirection: 'left-to-right',
                    itemOpacity: 0.85,
                    symbolSize: 20,
                    effects: [
                        {
                            on: 'hover',
                            style: {
                                itemOpacity: 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]}
            animate={true}
            motionStiffness={90}
            motionDamping={15}
        />
    )
}

export default MyResponsiveBar;
```

index.js (My implementation of rendering the Bar)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MyResponsiveBar from './graphBar'

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <div style={{height:500}}>
        <MyResponsiveBar />
    </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

As stated in the title running this code will result in an error stating `TypeError: instruction.match is not a function`

Webpage Error Report

```
TypeError: instruction.match is not a function
getInheritedColorGenerator
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/nivo/lib/lib/colors/inherit.js:78
  75 | }
  76 | 
  77 | if (instruction === 'inherit') return inheritGenerator;
> 78 | var inheritMatches = instruction.match(/inherit:(darker|brighter)\(([0-9.]+)\)/);
     | ^  79 | 
  80 | if (inheritMatches) {
  81 |   var method = inheritMatches[1];
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/nivo/lib/components/charts/bar/enhance.js:53
  50 | }), (0, _withPropsOnChange2.default)(['labelTextColor'], function (_ref2) {
  51 |   var labelTextColor = _ref2.labelTextColor;
  52 |   return {
> 53 |     getLabelTextColor: (0, _colors.getInheritedColorGenerator)(labelTextColor, 'axis.textColor')
     | ^  54 |   };
  55 | }), (0, _withPropsOnChange2.default)(['labelLinkColor'], function (_ref3) {
  56 |   var labelLinkColor = _ref3.labelLinkColor;
View compiled
new WithPropsOnChange
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/recompose/withPropsOnChange.js:96
  93 |     args[_key] = arguments[_key];
  94 |   }
  95 | 
> 96 |   return _ret = (_temp = (_this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Component.call.apply(_Component, [this].concat(args))), _this), _this.computedProps = propsMapper(_this.props), _temp), _possibleConstructorReturn(_this, _ret);
     | ^  97 | }
  98 | 
  99 | WithPropsOnChange.prototype.componentWillReceiveProps = function componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
View compiled
constructClassInstance
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11786
  11783 |     new ctor(props, context); // eslint-disable-line no-new
  11784 |   }
  11785 | }
> 11786 | var instance = new ctor(props, context);
        | ^  11787 | var state = workInProgress.memoizedState = instance.state !== null && instance.state !== undefined ? instance.state : null;
  11788 | adoptClassInstance(workInProgress, instance);
  11789 | {
View compiled
updateClassComponent
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15264
  15261 |   } // In the initial pass we might need to construct the instance.
  15262 | 
  15263 | 
> 15264 |   constructClassInstance(workInProgress, Component, nextProps, renderExpirationTime);
        | ^  15265 |   mountClassInstance(workInProgress, Component, nextProps, renderExpirationTime);
  15266 |   shouldUpdate = true;
  15267 | } else if (current$$1 === null) {
View compiled
beginWork
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16262
  16259 | 
  16260 |     var _resolvedProps = workInProgress.elementType === _Component2 ? _unresolvedProps : resolveDefaultProps(_Component2, _unresolvedProps);
  16261 | 
> 16262 |     return updateClassComponent(current$$1, workInProgress, _Component2, _resolvedProps, renderExpirationTime);
        | ^  16263 |   }
  16264 | 
  16265 | case HostRoot:
View compiled
performUnitOfWork
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20279
  20276 |   startProfilerTimer(workInProgress);
  20277 | }
  20278 | 
> 20279 | next = beginWork(current$$1, workInProgress, nextRenderExpirationTime);
        | ^  20280 | workInProgress.memoizedProps = workInProgress.pendingProps;
  20281 | 
  20282 | if (workInProgress.mode & ProfileMode) {
View compiled
workLoop
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20320
  20317 | if (!isYieldy) {
  20318 |   // Flush work without yielding
  20319 |   while (nextUnitOfWork !== null) {
> 20320 |     nextUnitOfWork = performUnitOfWork(nextUnitOfWork);
        | ^  20321 |   }
  20322 | } else {
  20323 |   // Flush asynchronous work until there's a higher priority event
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:147
  144 |     window.event = windowEvent;
  145 |   }
  146 | 
> 147 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
      | ^  148 |   didError = false;
  149 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  150 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:196
  193 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  194 | 
  195 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 196 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
      | ^  197 | 
  198 | if (windowEventDescriptor) {
  199 |   Object.defineProperty(window, 'event', windowEventDescriptor);
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallback
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:250
  247 | function invokeGuardedCallback(name, func, context, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  248 |   hasError = false;
  249 |   caughtError = null;
> 250 |   invokeGuardedCallbackImpl$1.apply(reporter, arguments);
      | ^  251 | }
  252 | /**
  253 |  * Same as invokeGuardedCallback, but instead of returning an error, it stores
View compiled
replayUnitOfWork
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19503
  19500 | 
  19501 | isReplayingFailedUnitOfWork = true;
  19502 | originalReplayError = thrownValue;
> 19503 | invokeGuardedCallback(null, workLoop, null, isYieldy);
        | ^  19504 | isReplayingFailedUnitOfWork = false;
  19505 | originalReplayError = null;
  19506 | 
View compiled
renderRoot
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20433
  20430 | if (true && replayFailedUnitOfWorkWithInvokeGuardedCallback) {
  20431 |   if (mayReplay) {
  20432 |     var failedUnitOfWork = nextUnitOfWork;
> 20433 |     replayUnitOfWork(failedUnitOfWork, thrownValue, isYieldy);
        | ^  20434 |   }
  20435 | } // TODO: we already know this isn't true in some cases.
  20436 | // At least this shows a nicer error message until we figure out the cause.
View compiled
performWorkOnRoot
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21357
  21354 |   cancelTimeout(timeoutHandle);
  21355 | }
  21356 | 
> 21357 | renderRoot(root, isYieldy);
        | ^  21358 | finishedWork = root.finishedWork;
  21359 | 
  21360 | if (finishedWork !== null) {
View compiled
performWork
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21267
  21264 |   }
  21265 | } else {
  21266 |   while (nextFlushedRoot !== null && nextFlushedExpirationTime !== NoWork && minExpirationTime <= nextFlushedExpirationTime) {
> 21267 |     performWorkOnRoot(nextFlushedRoot, nextFlushedExpirationTime, false);
        | ^  21268 |     findHighestPriorityRoot();
  21269 |   }
  21270 | } // We're done flushing work. Either we ran out of time in this callback,
View compiled
performSyncWork
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21241
  21238 | }
  21239 | 
  21240 | function performSyncWork() {
> 21241 |   performWork(Sync, false);
        | ^  21242 | }
  21243 | 
  21244 | function performWork(minExpirationTime, isYieldy) {
View compiled
requestWork
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21096
  21093 | 
  21094 | 
  21095 | if (expirationTime === Sync) {
> 21096 |   performSyncWork();
        | ^  21097 | } else {
  21098 |   scheduleCallbackWithExpirationTime(root, expirationTime);
  21099 | }
View compiled
scheduleWork
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20909
  20906 | !isWorking || isCommitting$1 || // ...unless this is a different root than the one we're rendering.
  20907 | nextRoot !== root) {
  20908 |   var rootExpirationTime = root.expirationTime;
> 20909 |   requestWork(root, rootExpirationTime);
        | ^  20910 | }
  20911 | 
  20912 | if (nestedUpdateCount > NESTED_UPDATE_LIMIT) {
View compiled
scheduleRootUpdate
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21604
  21601 | 
  21602 |   flushPassiveEffects();
  21603 |   enqueueUpdate(current$$1, update);
> 21604 |   scheduleWork(current$$1, expirationTime);
        | ^  21605 |   return expirationTime;
  21606 | }
  21607 | 
View compiled
updateContainerAtExpirationTime
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21630
  21627 |     container.pendingContext = context;
  21628 |   }
  21629 | 
> 21630 |   return scheduleRootUpdate(current$$1, element, expirationTime, callback);
        | ^  21631 | }
  21632 | 
  21633 | function findHostInstance(component) {
View compiled
updateContainer
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21698
  21695 |   var current$$1 = container.current;
  21696 |   var currentTime = requestCurrentTime();
  21697 |   var expirationTime = computeExpirationForFiber(currentTime, current$$1);
> 21698 |   return updateContainerAtExpirationTime(element, container, parentComponent, expirationTime, callback);
        | ^  21699 | }
  21700 | 
  21701 | function getPublicRootInstance(container) {
View compiled
ReactRoot.push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22011
  22008 |     work.then(callback);
  22009 |   }
  22010 | 
> 22011 |   updateContainer(children, root, null, work._onCommit);
        | ^  22012 |   return work;
  22013 | };
  22014 | 
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22163
  22160 |     if (parentComponent != null) {
  22161 |       root.legacy_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(parentComponent, children, callback);
  22162 |     } else {
> 22163 |       root.render(children, callback);
        | ^  22164 |     }
  22165 |   });
  22166 | } else {
View compiled
unbatchedUpdates
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21486
  21483 |     }
  21484 |   }
  21485 | 
> 21486 |   return fn(a);
        | ^  21487 | } // TODO: Batching should be implemented at the renderer level, not within
  21488 | // the reconciler.
  21489 | 
View compiled
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22159
  22156 | } // Initial mount should not be batched.
  22157 | 
  22158 | 
> 22159 | unbatchedUpdates(function () {
        | ^  22160 |   if (parentComponent != null) {
  22161 |     root.legacy_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(parentComponent, children, callback);
  22162 |   } else {
View compiled
render
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22234
  22231 |   {
  22232 |     !!container._reactHasBeenPassedToCreateRootDEV ? warningWithoutStack$1(false, 'You are calling ReactDOM.render() on a container that was previously ' + 'passed to ReactDOM.%s(). This is not supported. ' + 'Did you mean to call root.render(element)?', enableStableConcurrentModeAPIs ? 'createRoot' : 'unstable_createRoot') : void 0;
  22233 |   }
> 22234 |   return legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer(null, element, container, false, callback);
        | ^  22235 | },
  22236 | unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer: function (parentComponent, element, containerNode, callback) {
  22237 |   !isValidContainer(containerNode) ? invariant(false, 'Target container is not a DOM element.') : void 0;
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/src/index.js:12
   9 |     </div>
  10 |   </div>
  11 | );
> 12 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  13 | // import React, { Fragment } from "react";
  14 | // import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  15 | // import { line, area } from "d3-shape";
View compiled
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/webpack/bootstrap:781
  778 | };
  779 | 
  780 | // Execute the module function
> 781 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  782 | 
  783 | // Flag the module as loaded
  784 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/webpack/bootstrap:149
  146 |         );
  147 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  148 |     }
> 149 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  150 | };
  151 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  152 |     return {
View compiled
0
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:392:18
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/webpack/bootstrap:781
  778 | };
  779 | 
  780 | // Execute the module function
> 781 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  782 | 
  783 | // Flag the module as loaded
  784 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | return result;
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ReactCollection/songs/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
```

Any tips or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you sir, this was the problem with mine as well, had to remove all instances of  from: 'color' and it worked, however I don't know why this was a problem

Answer (score 1):

Issue was found the syntax used `labelTextColor={{ from: 'color', modifiers: [ [ 'darker', 1.6 ] ] }}` is not a valid syntax. Hence variables such as labelTextColor or borderColor requires a color code assigned to it.

Comment: how did you assign `labelTextColor` then?

Comment: found: `labelTextColor="#737373"`